# Passing an input stream to ffmpeg through Runtime.exec()

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg to read a video that gets streamed into a Java `InputStream` of some kind, **without having to write it to a file**, and then use ffmpeg to finalize the processing of a file, hopefully via its standard input.

I want to do this with the `ProcessBuilder` or `Process` objects. Is this possible to do, and if so, how? If it's not possible with these objects, would it be possible to do so with an ffmpeg wrapper?

Comment: You can get an OutputStream from a Process object, but I'm not sure if ffmpeg can support output since it looks like it requires a file parameter for it's output, that you can use as input for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Just use fifo files, both Java and ffmpeg treat them as plain files. You can create the fifo file by calling `mkfifo` using `Runtime.exec()` or from a setup script.

Comment: On Linux with no problem. Windows has no native _named_ pipes (it does have anonymous pipes), but you can use the Cygwin `mkfifo` .

Comment: Further checking, you probably don't need the entire Cygwin payload, you may be able to use just `mkfifo` from GNUWin32 Coreutils at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm . I didn't try that myself though, my experience with mkfifo under Windows has been under Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Below's sample code which creates a ffmpeg Process and grabs its output into a InputStream. Trick is to make ffmpeg return the output to stdin and grab the process's inputStream. 
Do note that this doesn't work for all the container formats like say **mp4** or **mov** which are seekable containers unlike mpeg-ts (due to the pointers to exact location in video file that's present in those containers, like the stco sub-atom in moov atom of a mp4 file, which cannot be determined midway during ffmpeg operation)

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(
            "/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6.3/bin/ffmpeg", // ffmpeg location
            "-re",
            "-i", "/Users/Downloads/videoTests/1.mp4", // input file
            "-vcodec", "libx264",
            "-s", "640x320",
            //"-r", "24",
            "-acodec", "libmp3lame",
            "-f", "mpegts",
            "-" // this tells ffmpeg to outout the result to stdin
    ).start();
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            //do whatever has to be done with inputStream
        }
    }.start();
}
```